# Set .net SqlDatasource Cache to expire at a certain time, every 10 mins on the clock

Tags: .net, webforms, sqldatasource

I have a .net website, a browser game, where the entire game "flips a turn" every 10 minutes, the turn flip itself takes 5-10 seconds. I have a lot of GridViews bound to relatively heavy queries in sqldatasource objects which 100s of players refresh between turns. Virtually nothing changes on these grids between turns, all the real  updating happens during a turn flip, so I want to enable caching on these grids because they are relatively heavy queries. However the turns flip ON every 10nth minute on the clock, not "every 10 minutes".  I can't just set the CacheDuration to be 600 because depending on when you first access the particular grid, 10 minutes from then could be well across into another turn.

I need a way to set the CacheDuration dynamically so it expires right as the 10nth minute on the clock hits. I imagine a couple ways I could do this:

I could check whether a Cache exists for the particular sqldatasource being bound and if it doesn't then check against the current time and set the cache duration appropriately so it expires on the 10nth minute.

OR

Perhaps if there is a clean way to clear all the caches across a set of sqldatasources when any page loads on a different turn than the last turn. There is already an application level variable keeping track of what turn the games on and detects when a page loads on a different turn. That could trigger such a cache clearing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had this exact need and came up with this. In my case I need the server cache to expire at 12 minutes after the hour.

Set the following attributes on the sqldatasource in .aspx

```
datasourcemode="DataSet" enablecaching="true" cachekeydependency="ckd12MinAfter" cacheexpirationpolicy="Absolute" cacheduration="Infinite"
```

In Page_Load codebehind

```
DateTime nextRefresh DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour).AddHours(DateTime.Now.Minute > 10 ? 1 : 0).AddMinutes(12);
if (Cache["ckd12MinAfter"] == null) { Cache.Add("ckd12MinAfter", "ckd12MinAfter", null, nextRefresh, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null); }
```

To force the client side refresh:

```
<script type='javascript'>
  function reloadAfterHour(r) { // force a reload at the next r minutes after the top of the hour
    var now = new Date(), m = now.getMinutes(), h = now.getHours() + (m < r ? 0 : 1), t = new Date(now.toDateString())
    , n = new Date(); n.setTime(t.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (r * 60 * 1000)); ms = (n.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, ms);
  }
  $(document).ready(function (e) { reloadAfterHour(12); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net web applications are event oriented, so what you want to do on page load is...

1. set up a table to log your cache expiration event
2. use a query to check the log table on page load to see if the cache has been expired based on the current time. ie: if the last time the cache was expired was before the last 10 minute mark, then it needs to be expired now.
3. trigger the cache expiration if necessary.

In other words, it doesn't matter if the cache is still active if no pages are reading it, but when someone goes to access it you just need to make sure your last expiration event was within the current 10 minute window.

Let me know if there is specific code that I might be able to help with. Post code attempts for me to evaluate.

HTH

Comment: Instead of checking a timestamp, I can check the Current Game Turn, if it changes then I know to expire all the caches. I already grab the current game turn on every page load, where necessary. 

Can't I use "CacheDependency" for this? Make the CacheDpeendency based on a variable? Or perhaps I can store the current turn into an application level variable. If the turn changes then the cache will drop.